# Facebook not showing title, description and thumbnail while sharing my website link

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, thumbnails

Everything was fine till morning. Then, I realised that facebook isnot showing description and thumbnail while sharing the link. Here is the debug link: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fmagazine177.com%2F

Here is my website: https://magazine177.com/

Can anybody tell me what is the problem please? Its really important

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: It has been fixed? Remember to click "Scrape again" if the content is "out of sync" when sharing.

Comment: It says "An internal error occurred while linting the URL." if I try to scrap the homepage. The interesting this is thumbnails are showing on mobile, when you browse from mobile it shows, but not from laptop. Help me Please :)